# Как получить только группы, не содержащие определённого значения элемента?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть запрос:

```
select 
 a,
 b,
 count(a),
 LISTAGG(d, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d desc) "d",
from
 table
where
 a = 1
 and b = 1
group by (a, count(a))
having (count(a) > 3)
```

Вывод запроса следующий:

```
   a    | b    | count(a) | d
   ----------------------------------
   qwe  | asd  | 3        | 8,8,8,5
   qwe1 | asd1 | 3        | 8,8,8,9,9
   qwe2 | asd2 | 3        | 8,8,8,5
```

Как прописать условие так, чтобы строки, где в колонке `d` присутствует 5 не выводились?

Т.е. вывод должен быть только 2-й строки:

```
   a    | b    | count(a) | d
   ----------------------------------
   qwe1 | asd1 | 3        | 8,8,8,9,9
```

Comment: having(count(a) > 3 AND NOT CONTAINS(d, '5', 1) > 0)

Comment: при выполнении пишет ошибку
 PLS-307: too many declarations of 'CONTAINS' match this call

Comment: `having (count(a) > 3) and (0=sum(case when d=5 then 1 else 0 end))`

Comment: видимо надо обернуть ваш запрос в подзапрос и уже по колонке d сделать условие отбора в where, примерно так: select r.* from (ваш группировочный запрос) r where r.d not like '%5%'. врочем, выше вам уже дали вариант лучше

Comment: @Konst Не... попадётся d=153 какой-нить, к гадалке не ходи.

Comment: Спасибо запрос
having (count(a) > 3) and (0=sum(case when d=5 then 1 else 0 end))
Помог

Comment: @Akina Почему ответ только в комментарии? Тут такое поле  "Ваш ответ" есть, трудно не заметить.

Comment: @0xdb Ответ тривиален, ибо вопрос вызван слабым знанием языка. Вероятность, что у кого-то возникнет такая же проблема (ну если не считать ещё одного студента в следующем году, которому попадётся то же задание) близка к нулевой. И соответственно ценность ответа - такая же. Ну и нафига?

Comment: @Akina И что? Здесь больше половины таких вопросов. Изменил заголовок в надежде поднять надобность вопроса.

Comment: @0xdb Ну скорее пошло бы что-то типа "Как получить только группы, не содержащие определённого значения элемента" или около того. Да вот только меня сильно сомневает, что даже в случае, когда страждущий озаботится поиском, ему удастся правильно составить запрос к поисковику. Благо есть их у меня под рукой, таких товарищей. Смотришь задачу, смотришь поисковый запрос - и прям умиляешься...

Comment: @Akina Точно, поправте.

Comment: @0xdb Ок, поправил. И даже таки сподобился написать ответ... только один хрен никто его не найдёт, если разве кто помнящий тыкнет только.

Comment: Пускай учаться искать. "Умён, не тот, кто всё знает - всё знать невозможно, а тот кто умеет быстро найти" (с) Народная мудрость.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отбросить группы, где есть элемент(ы) с заданным значением, надо сперва посчитать количество элементов с таким значением в группе.

Задача решается обычным приведением значения элемента к виду "1 - есть, 0 - нет", и суммированием приведённых значений - итогом будет количество элементов с заданным значением в конкретной группе. Ну а потом - если элементов нет, сумма будет ноль, иначе не ноль,- а это легко проверить.

Итого:

```
-- берём исходный авторский запрос
select a, b, count(a), LISTAGG(d, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d desc) "d",
from table
where a = 1 and b = 1
group by (a, count(a))
having (count(a) > 3)
-- и добавляем нашу проверку
AND (0 = SUM( CASE WHEN d=5 
                   THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0 
                   END
            )
    )
```

Если таких нежелательных значений несколько, то в условии CASE будет проверка не на равенство (`d=5`), а на вхождение в список (например, `d IN (5,7,9)`). Или в диапазон (`d BETWEEN 5 AND 9`).

Способ легко модифицируется для проверки других вариантов:

- в группе есть определённое значение - проверяем `SUM>0`
- в группе есть заданное количество определённого(ых) значения(й) - проверяем `SUM=n` (если количество задано строго), либо `SUM>=n` (если задано "не менее"), либо `SUM BETWEEN m AND n` (если задано "от и до")

Если условий несколько (например, "есть хотя бы две записи с d=5 и нет ни одной записи с e=8") - для каждого пишется своя проверка, со своим SUM и критерием.

Ну и прочие вариации. Скажем, "количество записей d=5 больше, чем записей d=7" - ну тут придётся сравнивать две разных SUM.